# How to customize number rounding

Tags: ruby, rounding

I'm trying to find a way to round money objects in Rails. I want to round numbers like this:

```
227493 -> 227500
279992 -> 280000
346824 -> 346900
455318 -> 455400
```

I want to round the last three digits to the next number.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Divide the number by 100, `ceil`, multiply the number by 100. There is nothing "custom" about it, it's simple math.

Comment: In Python, you'd do `number += -number % 100`. I'm not sure whether this works in Ruby, too.

Comment: From experiments at the `irb` prompt, looks like it does work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to see your attempt at a solution. As is it looks like you want us to write the code for you, which isn't what Stack Overflow is for. We expect you to research, to try, and when you've exhausted yourself then ask a specific question about the code you've written. Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]", and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide the number by 100 and round the value.

```
(227493.to_f / 100).round
 => 2275
```

Then convert back the number multiplying by 100. You can also use `divmod(100)` and then apply your custom rounding function based on the result.

```
227493.divmod(100)
 => [2274, 93]
```

Comment: Should be using `ceil`